# How to proceed once git origin was forcefully pushed

Tags: git, repository

My remote origin of git is pushed with non fast-forwarding commit. (I know its bad) how can I gracefully proceed without cloning again. I am also trying to cherry-pick my changes over the updated origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First do (if you didn't do it already):

```
git fetch
```

Then assuming our local branch that was forcefully pushed upstream is "master", switch to it:

```
git checkout master
```

Next, re-base your work on top of the new "origin/master":

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Now you can push your changes back to the origin as normally would.

Alternatively if you didn't have local changes that you were planning to push, you could simply do:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```